# automatically select sha's to edit during git rebase

Tags: git

I have a branch with a few dozen commits that was recently rebased on top of `master`. During conflict resolution some mistakes were made and now half a dozen of those commits need to be edited.

The list of sha's that need to be edited can be found via:

```
$ git log --format=format:%H master..branch-in-question -- file/path
```

Which can be used with `git rebase -i` to individually select each one for `edit` (and would probably be faster than taking the time to ask this question, but I'm sure you all understand). My question is whether it's possible to pass in the list of sha's from the `git log` above into `git rebase` and have it automatically select those commits for `edit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in way to do this, but I have a workaround that should [save you some time](https://xkcd.com/1205/).

First, start the interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i
```

Change the command for the first (and only the first) commit from `pick` to `edit`, then save and exit.

Run this [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for sha in $(git log --format=format:%H master..branch-in-question -- file/path)
do
  sha=${sha:0:7}
  sed -i "s/pick $sha/edit $sha/" .git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
done
```

Then do:

```
git rebase --continue
```

This pauses the rebase immediately, applies the edits that you would have done by hand to the todo file, and continues.

You are not able to create the todo file ahead of time, because doing so causes Git to assume that you have already started the rebase.

---

Thanks to some help from @torek, I have a way to automate this. Modify the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# editor=$(git config --get core.editor);
# editor=${editor:-${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}};
for sha in $(git log --format=format:%H master..branch-in-question -- file/path)
do
  sha=${sha:0:7}
  sed -i "s/pick $sha/edit $sha/" $@
done

# $editor $@
```

(If you want a chance to modify the todo file before running the rebase, uncomment the `editor` lines.)

Then, start the rebase as:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=/path/to/script.sh git rebase -i
```

This will automatically change the command for *all* commits output by your command from `pick` to `edit`, without the need to manually change the first commit yourself.

---

Neither version of the script allows you to customize what command is run to calculate which commits to use, but if this is an issue, you could probably pass in an environment variable to allow such customization.

Comment: You could modify this script to do the editing on a file supplied as an argument, then run $editor (set from `core.editor` or $VISUAL or $EDITOR or vi, in that order), and then set GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR to the script in the `git rebase -i`.  This relies on the fact that the command sequence gets edited by $GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR while commits get edited by `core.editor`. (Both fall back to `${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}`.)

Comment: @torek You lost me at the second step. How does `$editor` fit in?

Comment: I probably over-compressed the idea. In your script: `editor=$(git config --get core.editor); editor=${editor:-${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}}; <sed stuff>; $editor "$@"`. Then `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=<path to your script> git rebase -i <args>` will do what the OP wants, provided your script is modified slightly to edit "$@", without the need to do one pick-to-edit first. To handle older Git versions where the rebase-todo is not in `.git/rebase-merge/`, use "$@" to locate the file of commands.

Comment: @torek Okay, that got me a little closer. However, during my testing, (1) the last commit in my list stayed at `pick`, and (2) vi was opened at the start of the rebase (though all but the last commit had been changed from `pick` to `edit`). Any ideas?

Comment: Well, item 2 is intentional - just leave out the last `$editor` call if you don't want it (and then you can leave out the setting-up of local variable `$editor` in the first place). Not sure what is causing the non-change of the last "pick" though. Might be worth leaving some debug tracks, and/or building an all-at-once editing script so that you can run `sed` just once, both of which would help in figuring out item (1). (In any case this is a lot of work for what's probably a one-off task https://xkcd.com/1319/ :-) )

Comment: Thanks for all the help @torek! Very relevant xkcd, haha. And *facepalm*, the last commit wasn't changed because one of my test shas had one extra character, so it wasn't matching.

Comment: I was actually looking for the condiment-passing xkcd https://xkcd.com/974/ but I think the one I found ended up being more appropriate. :-)

Comment: Use the new `break` directive *before* the first commit instead of editing the first commit and you can catch that one too :)

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks!